# Update a column based on a JOIN between two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet-sql

Can you update a column in a TABLE based on a JOIN of two tables? Here is the code I have. I am getting a syntax error that says

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "Y" FROM HRBI LEFT JOIN Section16 ON HRBI.WorkerID = Section16.EEID

```
UPDATE HRBI 
SET HRBI.Section16 = 'Y'
FROM HRBI LEFT JOIN Section16 ON HRBI.WorkerID = Section16.EEID;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE HRBI 
LEFT JOIN Section16 ON HRBI.WorkerID = Section16.EEID
SET HRBI.Section16 = 'Y'
```

`set` should be after `join` conditions.

Comment: Thanks. What would I do if I wanted to have the condition to SET HRBI.Section16 = 'Y' only if it was Yes in Section16 Table?

Comment: add a `where` condition after `set`. like `where section16.section16 = 'Y'`